# Designing the design for the database of an e-commerce application

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Hi I am in the process of developing an e-commerce application and I seem to have some problems in designing my database for product catalog.

I have also read other similar questions on stackoverflow but I do not feel they provide the answer I need.

This are the requirements:

The product catalog should be structured by categories , each category will have an unknown number o subcategories , and each subcategory an  unknown number of products.

The application should have the capability of adding categories , subcategories and products at will.

The subcategory will decide the property for each product type.

Taking into account what I just mentioned I will provide an example as well as the 3 option I considered and why I believe they are not good.

Lets consider a Computer and a washing machine:
computer properties - VideoCard , ProcesorType,Memmory
washing machine -Putere(w) , Maximum Preasure , Water filter

Both products will belong to different categories and subcategories:
computer - PC category
Washing Machine - Electronics category.

Candidate I :
[image]
In this case all products properties except the common one like name and price will be stored in ProductType.But this will result in  alot of NULL values  and a mantainence nightmare.And I do not think I can create aditional product types because that will result in the need of chanching the ProductType table to add aditional columns.There are also some problems regarding the way I access data that I considered but they are not relevant to this question I think.

Candidate II:

[image]

In this case every product type will have a separate table with it's properties.But I will access the data for each product I will have to create a separate call to the database resulting in alot of steps being repeated.
Also I do not see any way how I can make the application be able to add aditional product , categories and subcateogries types without the need of a developer to do it.

Candidate III:

[image]

In this case I will store every property in key value pair inside the FormattedProperties.
I will also store the name of the class that is my model in the className column.And when I access the data I would use reflection to check for the specific class and both to initialize my object.

I'm prety sure that this would work , but I do not think that storing ever propery in a formated key-value pair string is the best way to go and is probably not a good practice either.
Also I know that reflection is preety slow and there will probably be a performance penalty.

Are there any other better options I could take into consideration in designing my database?
Some examples or links would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you decided what environment and framework the app will run on? Perhaps using Entity Framework or Hibernate would make this process painless - the product types would just enums in C#/Java and map to a single column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking subtypes or Products, where each product is exactly one subtype

Candidate 1 is called a "Table Per Hierarchy" or TPH. One table captures all different subtypes. This will get messy for many subtypes: it only works for a handful

Candidate 2 is called a "Table Per Type" or TPT. You have one table per subtype. In the Product table you have a column to define type (already there, called a Discriminator) with a super key on ProductID and the Discriminator. Again, this gets messy with many types.

Candidate 3 is called, er, *something*. And it the simplest way where you have lots of subtypes. It seems inefficient, but it best for scaling with many different subtypes because of the overhead of TPT and TPH designs

Personally, I'd use TPT for a few well defined subtypes but the 3rd design for many subtypes. I dislike the TPH redundant columns because of wasted disk and memory (for fixed length columns then space is allocated even when NULL)

Comment: Minor correction: TPH requires a discriminator-column to identify the type, not TPT.
In TPT the type can instead be deduced by checking the content of the subtype tables (fx through inner join).